# new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true))) is not printing

Tags: java, io, writer

I want this to write to output.txt without clearing it - just appending to the end. However, when I use the following two methods:

```
public void addEmails(ArrayList<String> emails){
    for (int i = 0; i < emails.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(emails.get(i));
        writer.println(emails.get(i));

        if (i == emails.size() - 1){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            writer.println();
            writer.println();
        }
    }

}

public void addFileName(String fn){
    String fileName = fn.replace("%DATE%.%FORMAT%", "");
    writer.println(fileName);
    writer.println();
    System.out.println(fileName);
    System.out.println();
}
```

These are called from the following methods:

```
public void analyze(String path){

     try {  
            System.out.println(path);



         File inputFile = new File(path);
         InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(inputFile);
         Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");

         InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
         is.setEncoding("UTF-8");




         SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
         SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
         DescriptorHandler descHandler = new DescriptorHandler(this);
         saxParser.parse(is, descHandler);  
         reader.close();
         writer.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }



}
```

Saxparser.parse uses the following overloaded methods for DefaultHandler:

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("student")) {
    // String rollNo = attributes.getValue("rollno");
    // System.out.println("Roll No : " + rollNo);
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("DestinationGroup")) {
        bDestinationGroup = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("EmailDestination")) {
        bEmailDestination = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Filename")) {
        bFileName = true;
    }

}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("DestinationGroup")) {

        descriptorAnalyzer.addFileName(filename);

        descriptorAnalyzer.addEmails(emails);

        emails.clear();


        bDestinationGroup = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {


    if (bEmailDestination) {
        String s = new String(ch, start, length);
        emails.add(s);
        bEmailDestination = false;
    }

    else if (bFileName) {
        filename = new String(ch, start, length);
        bFileName = false;
    }

}
```

The declaration (called on program start-up):

```
    writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true)));
```

System.out.println() is doing exactly what I want. However, output.txt remains unchanged.

Edit: it now writes to the file, but instead of appending it, it clears it and writes again.

Edit again: I misunderstood. After some more testing, it only writes to the file on the first call of analyze(). On subsequent calls, it does nothing.

Edit 3: Solved the problem but using flush() instead of close(), so the printwriter does not close. I believe that the printwriter closing is what caused the failure on subsequent writes.

Comment: You need to close streams/writers when they have done their work. Also I don't see where you are calling your `addEmails` method.

Comment: I'm calling them elsewhere, where I'm generating the strings.

System.out.println() is printing the right stuff so the problem can't be there.

I'll try your solution.

Comment: I did what you said, but now, it doesn't append to the end of the file - it resets it. Updating the main thing.

Comment: I can't help you without seeing [code which will let me reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you add the definition of the `writer` variable?

Comment: Added all that stuff. Sorry, took a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BufferedWritter doesn't write data to the file every time you use println.
The whole point of it is to save it in a Buffer and then when the buffer is full it will write. Problems happen when you never reach the buffer maximum size and dont call flush on your writer.
It's the same for BufferedOutputStream.

So you should call writer.flush() before closing it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple class with the following main method

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.println("Hello World!");
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

This code did not append to the `output.txt` file unless I added the `writer.close()` method after I am done writing to the file. Alternatively, adding a call to `writer.flush()` also worked for me (without a call to `close()`). May be, you can try adding a call to `writer.flush()` after you are done writing.